# How to see all changes to a specific file across all branches?

Tags: mercurial

The project I'm working on using a lot of branches. I know there's been some changes to a particular file that I need on another branch, but I don't know what branch they were done on.

How can I find all changes done to a specific file, searching across all [named] branches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the question, but `hg log <filename>` shows all changesets that include changes to a file, no matter what (named or unnamed) branch they're on.